# Expand the height of css while onclick and close back using jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I trying to expand the height of the css to 200 when onclick to display the list of the bank and choose the bank icon however i wish to close back the height from css 200 to 102 when onclick the same button.

How do we do this ?

```js
$('#moreBanking').click(function() {
  $('.bank_list').css("height", "200px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div name="bankDisplay2" class="bank_list_main">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: thirdPayBank" class="bank_list" style="height: 102px;">
    <li data-bind="attr:{'data-key':key, 'data-code':bankcode}, css: memberModel.netbankCssClass($data), click: $root.netBankSelectBank" data-key="华夏银行" data-code="HXB" class="bank_17">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bank"></a>
    </li>

    <li data-bind="attr:{'data-key':key, 'data-code':bankcode}, css: memberModel.netbankCssClass($data), click: $root.netBankSelectBank" data-key="福建兴业银行" data-code="CIB" class="bank_11">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bank"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span id="moreBanking">更多银行</span>
</div>

<span id="moreBanking">更多银行</span> 
<< button
```

Comment: `class="bank_list_main"`  element does not have `bank_list` `className` at `html` at Question.

Comment: What about toggleClass   `$("#moreBanking").click(function(){
    $(".bank_list").toggleClass("someClass");`  or                                                   
`$('#moreBanking').toggle(function () {
    $(".bank_lis").css({height: "200px"});
}, function () {
    $(".bank_lis").css({height: "102px"});
});`
});

Comment: There are two elements having id `"moreBanking"` at `html`. `id` of element in `document` should be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using inline styling for the initial height, I would toggle a class like:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7z6m4jg/1/)

CSS:

```
.bank_list {
    height: 102px;
 }
.tall {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('#moreBanking').click(function(){
  $('.bank_list').toggleClass('tall'); // Will add/remove class on each click
});
```

Comment: Hi Derek , Thanks for the help , your code are perfect +1 for the Jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this?

```
var more = $('#moreBanking')
var list = $('.bank_list')
more.click(function() {
    if (list.classList.contains('bank_list--open') {
        list.classList.remove('bank_list--open')
        list.css("height","102px");
    } else {
        list.classList.add('bank_list--open')
        list.css("height","200px");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use 2 classes, expanded_bank_list and bank_list.

```
.expanded_bank_list {
    height: 200px;
}
```

And then toggle between them

```
$('#moreBanking').click( function() {
    if ($('.bank_list').hasClass('expanded_bank_list')) {
        $('.bank_list').removeClass('expanded_bank_list');
    } else {
        $('.bank_list').addClass('expanded_bank_list');
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two `moreBanking` element `id`s in `document`. `id` of element in `document` should be unique. Change or remove the duplicate `id`; store property values `"120px"`, `"200px"` in an array, use `Array.prototype.reverse()` to set `height` of `.bank_list_main` parent element of `.bank_list`

```js
var heights = ["120px", "200px"];
$('#moreBanking').click(function() {
  $('.bank_list_main').css("height", heights.reverse()[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="bankDisplay2" class="bank_list_main">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: thirdPayBank" class="bank_list" style="height: 102px;">
    <li data-bind="attr:{'data-key':key, 'data-code':bankcode}, css: memberModel.netbankCssClass($data), click: $root.netBankSelectBank" data-key="华夏银行" data-code="HXB" class="bank_17">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bank"></a>
    </li>

    <li data-bind="attr:{'data-key':key, 'data-code':bankcode}, css: memberModel.netbankCssClass($data), click: $root.netBankSelectBank" data-key="福建兴业银行" data-code="CIB" class="bank_11">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bank"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<span id="moreBanking">更多银行</span> 
<< button
```